# To print along with the textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript.
 I want to print the data that user writes in the textbox.The operation should go hand-in-hand i.w if he writes 2 it should be displayed 2 first then 23 then displayed 23 and so on.

```js
function onChange() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  Enter Your Name:<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="this.onChange();"> 

  Show::<span id="display"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no `this` before `onchange`.
- You can use `this.value` to directly access the `value` and use it instead of targeting the element again using `getElementById`.

```js
function onChange(value) {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  Enter Your Name:<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="onChange(this.value)"> Show::

  <span id="display"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @L_Church The semi-colon is not an error. Actually `onkeyup="onChange(this.value);console.log('you are wrong')"` works

Comment: I have tried previously with this also but it's not working when I'm executing through live preview but how it's working here. Even if after removing this also it's not working in my IDE(Using Crome to display). I'm using brackets. Is there anything to enable that i have not done

Comment: @RiaMohanty Look closely at your code, there is probably a typo or something

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```js
 function onChange() {
          document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
        }
```

```html
  <html>
        
        <head>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
          Enter Your Name:<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="onChange()"> Show::
        
          <span id="display"></span>
        </body>
        
        </html>
```